# how to fix the position of div to bottom right of div containing background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have html sturcture

```
<div id="bg" class="layer">
<img id="trackmap" src="images/back_2416.jpg" width="1208" height="768" class=" ui-draggable map-icon" usemap="#main-map" data-zoom-image="images/background_zoom.jpg" data-big="images/background_zoom.jpg" style="position: relative; left: -439px; top: -272.6px; margin: 0px; display: inline-block; height: 1327.2px; width: 2088px;">
<div id="nav-text">LOREM IPSUM.</div>
</div>
```

> Jquery

```
 var windowHeight = $("#trackmap").height();
 var windowWidth = $("#trackmap").width();
 var text_height=((windowHeight)-(100));
 $("#nav-text").css("top",windowHeight);
```

> Css

```
.layer {
position: absolute;
width: 1208px;
height: 768px;
}
#nav-text{
z-index: 200;
color: white;
position: absolute;
font-size: 10px;
margin-left: 715px;
width: 310px;
height: 10px;
position: fixed;
bottom: 5px;}
```

I just want to fix the `nav-text` to the bottom right whatsoever.. Now i problem i am facing is theres zoom function on the `trackmap`.. which increases the height and width of the image ..so the text comes in between of the image ..intereferring with the image.. I have tried taking the image `width height` using **jquery** ..but somehow its not working

[image: Black section is text]

Comment: You mention jquery not working, but I see no code

Comment: @WillP. I have added jquery code .. Thankq

Comment: Why are you setting top and bottom at the same time? top using jQuery and bottom using CSS?

Comment: Additionally.. to get you clear.. what you want is to always have the nav-text to the bottom right even if the image got zoomed in or out?

Comment: @MohammedR.El-Khoudary You are bang on ..correct.. Appreciate your response..

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I am following your issue here, but it sounds like you are trying to get a div to be in the bottom-right of another div no matter what size it is. That can be done by setting the parent div `position` to `relative` which you have, and the child div `position` to `absolute`. You have that set but then override it by setting the `position` to `fixed` lower in the CSS. You will also want to set the `bottom` to `0` and the `right` to `0`.

This will position the child div to the bottom right of the parent div. Then you can get rid of your jQuery. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: I think if position: fixed is assigned to a child of a position: absolute or relative parent it will be fixed relative to the window and not the containr

Comment: yeah it gets fixed and remains to bottom of the window which is not expected.. i want it shud be to the container..

Comment: Yeah. I was saying you should remove the position:fixed attribute completely. But I may be misunderstanding the question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. I am in a hurry to catch the bus.. but here's [a fiddle that illustrates the idea](http://jsfiddle.net/VM2R7/)..

basically you will need to use the scrolltop and left parameters to do so:

```
$(".container").on("scroll", function() {
$(".nav-text").css("top", $(this).prop("scrollTop") + 130);
$(".nav-text").css("left", $(this).prop("scrollLeft") + 120);
});
```

but move the scrolls first.. sorry I need to go now..

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by not fixing the .layer width and height, using display:inline-block; to prevent the div from filling the whole container width. At that point, the .layer size will match the image size whatever it is.
Finally you just need to set the text to absolute position and bottom and right properties too.

```
.parent{
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
}

.children{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
}
```

[Here is the fiddle explaining](http://jsfiddle.net/csLMM/)

And here is the proof it works even if the image size is changed(click on the image).

[Fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/csLMM/1/)

Comment: There must be something with your zoom function, can we get a preview of that function or how do it zoom?

Comment: let me give you exmample the zoom function increases the height by 200px..and there are three level of zoom.. intiially image lets consider 500px

Comment: does it change #trackmap height? or another container? on my 2nd example clicking on the image changes its height and it works

Comment: It must be css properties somewhere broking the whole thing, I'm afraid I can't help you more without some more testing meterials :(